# Android: How to seperate pure data from resources?

Tags: java, android

I am currently implementing the data layer of my app and just wondered what´s the best way to seperate pure data classes/information from corresponding android resources like strings, colors, etc.

For example:

```
public final class Location {
    public static final int NOT_SPECIFIED = 0;
    public static final int AT_HOME = 1;
    public static final int AT_WORK = 2;
    public static final int AWAY = 3;

    public static final int[] VALUES = {
            NOT_SPECIFIED, AT_HOME, AT_WORK, AWAY
    };

    @IntDef({ NOT_SPECIFIED, AT_HOME, AT_WORK, AWAY })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Locations {}

    private static String TXT_NOT_SPECIFIED;
    private static String TXT_AT_HOME;
    private static String TXT_AT_WORK;
    private static String TXT_AWAY;

    private Location() {}

    /**
     * Call once in Application.class to get a reference to the application context
     * in order to load the string representations for the single locations.
     *
     * @param applicationContext the app´s context
     */
    public static void init(Context applicationContext) {
        Resources res = applicationContext.getApplicationContext().getResources();

        /* Pre-load any string resources that correspond to locations. */
        TXT_NOT_SPECIFIED = res.getString(R.string.text_location_not_specified);
        TXT_AT_HOME = res.getString(R.string.text_location_at_home);
        TXT_AT_WORK = res.getString(R.string.text_location_at_work);
        TXT_AWAY = res.getString(R.string.text_location_away);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the string representation of a given <code>location</code>.
     *
     * @param location must be in range of 0-3
     *uhr
     * @return the string representing the <code>location</code>
     */
    public static String getStringForLocation(@Locations int location) {
        switch (location) {
            case NOT_SPECIFIED: return TXT_NOT_SPECIFIED;
            case AT_HOME: return TXT_AT_HOME;
            case AT_WORK: return TXT_AT_WORK;
            case AWAY: return TXT_AWAY;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("'location' must be in range of 0-3");  /* Should never be called actually. */
    }
```

The class itself contains the pure data representation of certain locations (instead of using `enum`). For every defined `location` there is a string representation stored in the `strings.xml` file. #
The problem now is: Multiple parts of my app need to get the name for a certain `location`. Instead of finding the resources every time I want them to be stored at exactly one place, so that if something changes (new `location` option added, etc.) I only have to touch the code in one place.

Currently I´ve implemented it like the above code shows: The `Location` class has a static init method which gets called in the App´s onCreate to get a `context` in order to load the string resoruces. (I know I could have just passed in the `context` as a parameter for the `getStringForLocation` method, couldn´t decide which one is better?)

However, this way I have android dependencies in my supposed pure data class.
What are good ways to seperate this dependencies while still maintaining the code that maps this data to a resource in one place? Having a static util method outside the data layer that does the mapping?

Comment: Why *not* use an `enum`?

Comment: As far as I understood that is not the preferred approach in android, because of memory or performance reasons. Android programmers suggest to use integer constants with the annotation IntDef. At least that is how I understood it. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite see why you want to preload the strings in some variables. My understanding is that getting a string from resources is not expensive in terms of performance.

I'd just use something like this:

```
public static String getLocationString(Context context, @Locations int location) {

    switch (location) {
        case NOT_SPECIFIED: return context.getString(R.string.text_location_not_specified);
        case AT_HOME: return context.getString(R.string.text_location_at_home);
        case AT_WORK: return context.getString(R.string.text_location_at_work);
        case AWAY: return context.getString(R.string.text_location_away);
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("'location' must be in range of 0-3");  /* Should never be called actually. */

}
```

and from an activity:

```
String myLocation = Location.getLocationString(this, Location.AT_HOME);
```

And you can get rid of `Location.init` method

Comment: Okay that makes it a lot cleaner, I agree. I didn´t know how much of an impact getting the resources has, so I thought it would be a good idea to load them at the start of the application. Regarding the placement of the code, would you keep it inside the _Location_ class or would you put it somewhere else? Thanks.

Comment: I usually have a MyAppHelper class in mypackage.utils folder, where I add all my shared constants and functions, like that one. `MyAppHelper.getLocationString(context, Location.AT_HOME)`, etc...

Comment: Ok that´s what I meant. Thanks for your answer :)